# How do I connect Nodemon with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, react-fullstack

I am learning **MongoDb** and was following a playlist and did everything accordingly. I am trying to connect database with Mongoose. But when I try to run `nodemon` I get the following error.
Please be informed MongoDB Server is running fine.

```
PS C:\Users\KIIT\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN\Web Development\Inotebook\inotebook_backend> nodemon .\index.js       
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node .\index.js`
Connected to Mongo Successfully
C:\Users\KIIT\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN\Web Development\Inotebook\inotebook_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\KIIT\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN\Web Development\Inotebook\inotebook_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:788:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\KIIT\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN\Web Development\Inotebook\inotebook_backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:763:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 5093783,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\KIIT\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN\Web Development\Inotebook\inotebook_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:367:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KIIT\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN\Web Development\Inotebook\inotebook_backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:290:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
            errno: -4078,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '::1',
            port: 27017
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v18.16.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

........................................................................................
i have a file named db.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"

const connectToMongo = async () => {
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
    console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully");
}

module.exports = connectToMongo
```

and index.js

```js
const connectToMongo = require('./db')
connectToMongo();
```

Comment: Looks like you call `connectToMongo` more than once

Comment: oh thank you. i got it fixed. chatgpt :)